# Cannot run peer because error when setting up MSP of type bccsp from directory: Fabric test-network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

Good day
I am new to Hyperledger fabric (using version 2.5.3) and struggling with test network. I am trying to interact with the network using peer CLi. I was following steps shown in the tutorial for using fabric test network. I have managed to do the following basic steps successfully:

- Bring up the test network
- Created a default channel (mychannel)
- Started a chaincode on the channel
- Added all binaries to CLI Path

Now when i run this command:

peer chaincode invoke -o localhost:7050 --ordererTLSHostnameOverride orderer.example.com --tls --cafile "${PWD}/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem" -C mychannel -n basic --peerAddresses localhost:7051 --tlsRootCertFiles "${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt" --peerAddresses localhost:9051 --tlsRootCertFiles "${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt" -c '{"function":"InitLedger","Args":[]}'

i get the error below:

**ERRO [main] InitCmd -> Cannot run peer because error when setting up MSP of type bccsp from directory /home/i5/go/src/github.com/oleteane/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp: KeyMaterial not found in SigningIdentityInfo**

Please help me to figure out what i am doing wrong.

Thank you in advance

Here is my screen

[my screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYyHp.png)

I have searched in the internet for the solution, but still failed to solve the problem